# Difficulty getting google-coral example-object-detection to work properly

Tags: python, gstreamer, google-coral

Noob here, trying to run google-coral example-object-detection on a new google mini dev board.  I have followed all of the instructions for set up of the device and loading the example, models, etc.  When I try to run detect with or without SORT tracking I get the same error shown below.  It seems the problem is with Gstreamer but I have no idea how to fix.  I have successfully used other examples within the google-coral database.

```
mendel@green-orange:~/google-coral/example-object-tracker/gstreamer$ python3 detect.py

(detect.py:1322): dconf-WARNING **: 13:21:55.165: Unable to open /usr/local/share/dconf/profile/user: Not a directory
Loading ../models/mobilenet_ssd_v2_coco_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite with ../models/coco_labels.txt labels.
Gstreamer pipeline:
 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! tee name=t
            t. ! queue max-size-buffers=1 leaky=downstream ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=300,height=225 ! videobox name=box autocrop=true
               ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=300,height=300 ! appsink name=appsink emit-signals=true max-buffers=1 drop=true
            t. ! queue max-size-buffers=1 leaky=downstream ! videoconvert
               ! rsvgoverlay name=overlay ! videoconvert ! ximagesink sync=false
            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect.py", line 218, in <module>
    main()
  File "detect.py", line 214, in main
    videofmt=args.videofmt)
  File "/home/mendel/google-coral/example-object-tracker/gstreamer/gstreamer.py", line 275, in run_pipeline
    pipeline = GstPipeline(pipeline, user_function, src_size, mot_tracker)
  File "/home/mendel/google-coral/example-object-tracker/gstreamer/gstreamer.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(pipeline)
gi.repository.GLib.Error: gst_parse_error: no element "ximagesink" (1)
```

Got some great feedback from Manoj to run : "sudo apt-get install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good python3-gst-1.0 python3-gi gir1.2-gtk-3.0 python3 -m pip install svgwrite"

Updated error:

```
mendel@green-orange:~/google-coral/example-object-tracker$ cd gstreamer
mendel@green-orange:~/google-coral/example-object-tracker/gstreamer$ sudo apt-get install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good python3-gst-1.0 python3-gi gir1.2-gtk-3.0 python3 -m pip install svgwrite
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pip
E: Unable to locate package install
E: Unable to locate package svgwrite
mendel@green-orange:~/google-coral/example-object-tracker/gstreamer$ pip install svgwrite
-bash: pip: command not found
mendel@green-orange:~/google-coral/example-object-tracker/gstreamer$ pip3 install svgwrite
Requirement already satisfied: svgwrite in /home/mendel/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.4.1)
mendel@green-orange:~/google-coral/example-object-tracker/gstreamer$ python3 detect.py

(detect.py:1316): dconf-WARNING **: 11:46:34.384: Unable to open /usr/local/share/dconf/profile/user: Not a directory
Loading ../models/mobilenet_ssd_v2_coco_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite with ../models/coco_labels.txt labels.
Gstreamer pipeline:
 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480,framerate=30/1 ! tee name=t
            t. ! queue max-size-buffers=1 leaky=downstream ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=300,height=225 ! videobox name=box autocrop=true
               ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=300,height=300 ! appsink name=appsink emit-signals=true max-buffers=1 drop=true
            t. ! queue max-size-buffers=1 leaky=downstream ! videoconvert
               ! rsvgoverlay name=overlay ! videoconvert ! ximagesink sync=false
            
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "detect.py", line 218, in <module>
    main()
  File "detect.py", line 214, in main
    videofmt=args.videofmt)
  File "/home/mendel/google-coral/example-object-tracker/gstreamer/gstreamer.py", line 275, in run_pipeline
    pipeline = GstPipeline(pipeline, user_function, src_size, mot_tracker)
  File "/home/mendel/google-coral/example-object-tracker/gstreamer/gstreamer.py", line 39, in __init__
    self.pipeline = Gst.parse_launch(pipeline)
gi.repository.GLib.Error: gst_parse_error: no element "ximagesink" (1)
```

Tried another suggestion and still no joy.  Any other thoughts?

```
mendel@green-orange:~/google-coral$ cd example-object-tracker
mendel@green-orange:~/google-coral/example-object-tracker$ cd gstreamer
mendel@green-orange:~/google-coral/example-object-tracker/gstreamer$ sudo apt-get install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good python3-gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location= python3-gi gir1.2-gtk-3.0 python3 -m pip3 install svgwrite
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python3-gst-launch-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'python3-gst-launch-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'python3-gst-launch-1.0'
E: Unable to locate package rtspsrc
E: Unable to locate package location
E: Unable to locate package pip3
E: Unable to locate package install
E: Unable to locate package svgwrite
```

Comment: Can you try to run : "sudo apt-get install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good python3-gst-1.0 python3-gi gir1.2-gtk-3.0
  python3 -m pip install svgwrite" ?

Comment: @Manoj thank you for your continued help, but no luck.  I ended up with the same error, though the packages you asked to run had an error.  I'll post the sequence in the edited question

Comment: Can you try to run  with gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=  ?

Comment: @Manoj thanks again for your support.  did you mean run that in the terminal in addition to your first suggestion?  I ran "sudo apt-get install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good python3-gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location= python3-gi gir1.2-gtk-3.0 python3 -m pip3 install svgwrite"
mendel@green-orange:~/google-coral/example-object-tracker/gstreamer$ sudo apt-get install -y gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-good python3-gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location= python3-gi gir1.2-gtk-3.0 python3 -m pip3 install svgwrite" and it was unable to locate packages.  I'll add up top

Comment: Let us discuss at : https://github.com/google-coral/example-object-tracker/issues/6#issuecomment-804547412

Answer (score 1):

Update: I had same issue just install these packages

```sh
sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could also edit your answer to explain the reason that the old approach of the OP does not work and how your solution fixes it. That way future viewers will be able to relate and understand the solution at glance. Thanks.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).